# What is the word for the ability to foresee?

Tags: word-request

What is the word for the quality to foresee? Note that, the word should **not** be related to specific fields like astrology. I am writing an article and the word should be such as it can be used in this place:

> The leader X was a great political personality at those unstable times after WWII. Alone he was able to show the hapless global economy, a ray of hope using his immense and distinguishing *******(the quality) which pushed him to reach the zenith of fame at that time.

Comment: I guess you're not looking for words like instinct or intuition? What about [second sight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_sight) or [extrasensory perception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrasensory_perception)?

Comment: @Em1, No, not exactly. Like I said its like _ability to foresee or to predict_.

Comment: Also its not like _second sight_ as you suggested. Its not that hard to perceive. Its more like the quality of a person to take decision/action based on his judgement on what is likely to happen in future upon observing the environment around him.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Foresight*.

From NOAD:

> **foresight** (*n.*) the ability to predict or the action of predicting what will happen or be needed in the future

Comment: Nice. That is the one I was looking for.

Comment: Synonym search also gave me a great word "prospicience" :)

Comment: @Mistu4u - Trust me, stick with _foresight_.

Comment: @Mistu4u That's a much rarer word!  It means *foresight* literally: it's `pro-` ("fore") and `spic-` (from *specere* "to see"), along with `-ience`.  Be careful not to misremember the end of the word as `science` ("knowledge"); the Latinate word for *foreknowledge* is `prescience`.

Comment: snailboat: Yes, so rare that some pretty decent dictionaries [don't even](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/spellcheck/english/prospicience)  [list it](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/spellcheck/british/?q=prospicience)!

Comment: @J.R., Wow, never seen a word before not listed in a dictionary!!!! I guess, I will leave that word behind.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I tend to use *foresight* when talking about someone knowing *some **specific** future thing*.

For the more general case (when someone is *consistently* able to predict how things will turn out), I'd be more likely to say they were [**prescient**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/prescient)

> [**prescience**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prescience) *- knowledge of events before they take place; foreknowledge.*

It may be worth pointing out that although [**foresight** is more common than **prescience**](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prescience,foresight&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) to name the ability itself, [**prescient** is far more common than **foresighted**](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prescient,foresighted&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) as an adjective to describe a person who has that ability (particularly in more recent decades).